# Types of heparin

Tags: biochemistry

My textbook(biochemistry 4th edition, U. Satyanarayana) says that the following structure is of heparin[image]

and it's name should be D-Glucuronate 2-sulfate, N-sulfoglucosamine 6-sulfate.
 I searched on internet but could not find this kind of heparin.
So could anyone give credibility that this structural compound is heparin?
Atlast **what is the criteria that determines whether the compound is a heparin?**

Comment: Why downvotes? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This structure is exactly the same structure as found [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heparin) at the very top the page. Other variations are also shown elsewhere on that page.

Perhaps you are being misled by the presence/absence of hydrogens on the sulfate groups? The way your textbook shows it is a more physiologically relevant way as those groups would be deprotonated in normal biological conditions, but this doesn't really change the chemical structure. Heparin is normally administered as a salt.

Further, heparin is a polysaccharide chain of varying lengths (more information on that same wikipedia page) - it doesn't really make sense to say that heparin's chemical name should be "D-Glucuronate 2-sulfate, N-sulfoglucosamine 6-sulfate" - this is the name of only one disaccharide in a long, long chain. Your textbook doesn't say that either, the little "n" in the lower right corner is very important and indicates a chain of unspecified length.

Comment: on what basis we classify those(other variations)  as heparin?

Comment: Wikipedia shows iduronate on the very first pic while the book depicts glucuronate.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct; if you read more on the wikipedia article it mentions  the composition of heparin which includes both - it really doesn't matter much which are depicted. Heparins are just glycosaminoglycans of a variety of subunits - there is no one specific chemical called "heparin" but they all have roughly the same biological function - welcome to biology :)

Comment: [This link](http://themedicalbiochemistrypage.org/glycans.php) might help you sort out some of the details in terms of where the boundaries are between heparins and similar compounds.